# Output to file doesn't look the way it should

Tags: php

So I try to send some output to a file but it doesn't look the way I want.
I have a file with some random integer values , it looks like this:

78, 60, 62, 68, 71, 68, 73, 85, 66, 64, 76, 63, 81, 76, 73, 68, 72, 73, 75, 65, 74, 63, 67, 65, 64, 68, 73, 75, 79, 73

4, 6, 9, 11, 16

9, 10, 16, 18, 20

1, 3, 8, 10, 15

Now what I want to do is for each of these lines print the average, max and min number into another file.
My code for this part is:

```
while (!feof($aFile))
    {
        $cnt += 1;
        $anArray = array();  
        $anArray = explode(",", fgets($aFile));
        
        foreach ($anArray as $value)
        {
            $value = (int)$value;
        }
        $line = "Line $cnt: Average=" . array_sum($anArray) / count($anArray) . " Max=" . max($anArray) . " Min=" . min($anArray);
        
        fwrite($resultsFile, $line);
        fwrite($resultsFile, "\n");
    
   }
```

The problem is that the resultsFile looks like this:

```
Line 1: Average=70.6 Max= 85 Min= 60

Line 2: Average=9.2 Max= 16

  Min=4

Line 3: Average=14.6 Max= 20

  Min=9

Line 4: Average=7.4 Max= 15 Min=1
```

I couldn't exactly copy paste this , because when I do it pastes it the right way
The problem is that it changes line and then prints Min .

Total Average=50.533333333333 Total Max= 85 Total Min=1

Comment: This isn't the problem but $value in your foreach loop isn't actually used. You can completely remove that loop.

Comment: Disable "Word wrap" on the application you used to view the file.

Comment: @imvain2 he probably wants to use `foreach ($anArray as &$value)`.

Comment: the foreach loop is to turn the each string element to int, i dont think this is the problem

Comment: i disabled word wrap, still doen't work

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda tricky and is a combination of several moments.

First - you have `new line` symbol (`\n`) in each string of your file.
So, for example string `9, 10, 16, 18, 20` is really a `9, 10, 16, 18, 20\n` string.

When you explode this string by `,`, last element of your `$anArray` is **not** `20`, but `20\n` (with new line).

Now you're trying to cast each element to int, but as **by default** php works with **copy** of array, your initial values in `$anArray` are **unchaged**. As correctly stated in comments - to apply changes to original array, use `$&value` notation:

```
foreach ($anArray as &$value)
{
    $value = (int)$value;
}
```

And last - all following operations on your `$anArray` silenlty cast `20\n` to int (`20`). But as noticed in [`max` manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php#refsect1-function.max-description), for example:

> The actual value returned will be of the original type with **no conversion applied**

So, in array `['9', '10', '16', '18', '20\n']` max value will be `20`, but returned value will be `20\n` which creates a new line and moves `Min=...` output to **next line**.